# name error 'html' not defined with beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

My python 3.4.4 code is:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html.parser import HTMLParser

urls = 'file:///C:/Users/tarunuday/Documents/scrapdata/mech.html'
htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile,html.parser)
```

I'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python34\saved\scrapping\scrapping2.py", line 7, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile,html.parser)
    NameError: name 'html' is not defined
```

Now I understand that HTMLParser is py2.x and html.parser is py3.x but how can I get this to work? The [bs4 site](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#problems-after-installation) says `If you get the ImportError “No module named html.parser”, your problem is that you’re running the Python 3 version of the code under Python 2.`, but I'm running 3.x and I'm getting a NameError not an ImportError

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is correct, you haven't defined `html` anywhere. The documentation you link to shows that you should be passing `"html.parser"` as a string; it doesn't look like you need to import HTMLParser at all.

Comment: holy... Wow man, FML. My bad. I spent a couple of hours on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `html.parser` is a string and if you are using python 3 or above, it needs quotes around it.