# Getting an error: name 'html' is not defined while trying to implement simple program for HTTP request response cycle using urllib library in python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parser

I am learning BeautifulSoup library in python and came across urllib library to understand more on HTTP request-response cycle.

In the following code, I'm trying to scrape all the anchor tags which are there on that HTML page and but getting an error: **NameError: name 'html' is not defined**

I tried to solve the problem using google and found the following relevant StackOverflow question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113811/name-error-html-not-defined-with-beautifulsoup4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113811/name-error-html-not-defined-with-beautifulsoup4%5D).

I tried the given solution but it couldn't work.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url=input('Enter- ')
req_file=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
tags=soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href',None))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing the read as variable `reg_file`:

`req_file=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()`

but when you try to pass it off to BeautifulSoup, it's looking for variable `html`, which hasn't been defined as anything, hence the `'html' is not defined` error

`soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")`

so the option is to either, store the `request` `.read()` as the variable `html`:

```
html=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
```

or pass what you have originally stored, `req_file` to BeautifulSoup:

```
req_file=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(req_file,"html.parser")
```

hope the explanation helps. I'm still learning BeautifulSoup, but can remember all the struggles at the beginning. It's fun once you get the hang of it a bit.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url=input('Enter- ')
req_file=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(req_file,"html.parser")
tags=soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href',None))
```