# Parsing an HTML Document with python

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing

I am totally new on python and i am trying to parse an HTML document to remove the tags and I just want to keep the title and the body from a newspaper website I have previously downloaded on my computer.

I am using the class HTML Parser I found on the documentation, but I dont know how to use it very well, I dont understand this language very well :(

This is my code:

```
#importa la clase HTMLParser
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class HTMLCleaner(HTMLParser):
    container = ""

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if (data == '\n'):
            pass
        elif (data == " "):
            pass
        else:
            self.container += data

        return self.container

parser = HTMLCleaner()

#se va a abrir un fichero para parsearlo
archivo = open("C://Users//jotab//OneDrive//Documentos//Git//SRI//SRI_PR0//coleccionESuja2019//es_26142.html", "r", encoding="utf8")


while True:
    line = archivo.readline()
    if line == "":
        break
    else:
        parser.feed(line)

print(parser.container)
```

I am doing this because I am getting a lot of lines "\n" and a lot of lines " " after parsing. But when I try to check if a line is a blankspace, it returns false even if both variables appear on the debugger exactly the same.

I don't know why this happens, but if some1 could help me to parse this, it would be so nice

Comment: *"check if a line is a blankspace"*: this does only compare **one** char: `data == " "`. Add `print(data)` before the line `if (data ...` to see what you get.

Comment: i did it, it printed a blankspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you provided it looks like you are trying to open a html file that you have.

Instead of parsing the html file line by line like you are doing. Just feed the parser the entire HTML file.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Encountered a start tag:", tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("Encountered an end tag :", tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Encountered some data  :", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()

with open(r'C:\Users\...site_1.html', "r") as f:
    page = f.read()
    tree = html.fromstring(page)
parser.feed(tree)
```

Pythons HTML parser requires the feed to be a string.
What you could do is copy paste the entire HTML that you have into the Feed. Might not be best practice but it should read and parse the html

```
parser.feed("THE ENTIRE HTML AS STRING HERE")
```

I hope this helps

Edit———-
Have you tried getting the html into a string like you have and then calling `str.strip()` on the string to remove all blank spaces from leading and trailing of the string.

FYI you can also use `sentence.replace(“ “, “”)` to remove all blank spaces from string

Hope this helps

Comment: That was the first I tried, to parse the whole document, but i got a lot of blank lines and a lot of blankspaces at start and end of a lot of lines, you can see graphically here:

https://gyazo.com/bfa12315276e1d447655a0f9d7c4d9be

Comment: I am gonna try it but i am not sure it would work, since those methods remove all the blankspaces in the line

Comment: Strip only removes spaces at the beginning and end of th string so if you take it Line by line you can strip the white space from each line

Comment: It worked! TYVM, now I just have to filter correctly my tags ^^

Comment: `name 'html' is not defined` ‍♂️

Comment: @Scott , look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/36113826/8272698